# IQueryable to IEnumerable in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Here's my code :

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        if(User.IsInRole("admin")){
            return View(await db.Customers.ToListAsync());
        }
        else if(User.IsInRole("employee"))
        {
            var list = from c in db.Customers
                       where c.User.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId()
                       select c;
            var e = list.AsEnumerable();                
            return View(e);


            //tried this too : 
            //var list = db.Customers.Where(c=>c.User == User); 
            //return View(list);

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Error");
    }
```

**VIEW :**

```
@model IEnumerable<AspnetIdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)

            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Why can't I display the Query results to the view ? Any help would be appreciated! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to something called *deferred execution*. You're returning an `IQueryable` instance.. but this instance doesn't hold the data you want. It contains an execution plan with which to query for your results.

You need to force evaluation of the query. The general way of doing this is calling `ToList()` (Notice that you've done this on your other logical branch for the `if` statement):

```
return View(list.ToList());
```

Your problem (and the reason it all compiles) is because `IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable`. So passing it to your view is fine. `IList` also implements `IEnumerable`.. so `ToList()` forces evaluation of your `IQueryable` and can still be passed to the view.

There is also this issue in the view (outside of the `foreach` loop):

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
```

Your model is a collection.. so this won't work, since `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a `UserName` property (but its items do).

Comment: Are you certain there's a need to eagerly execute the `IQueryable` by calling `ToList()`? The query will be executed during the view's foreach, as long as the stray `model => model.UserName` is fixed.

Comment: @Stephen What happens if the context isn't available anymore? When it attempts to iterate over the results in the view the context will be disposed..

Comment: A-ha, that is a good point. [I never call Dispose on my DbContexts](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html) so that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: Not being an EF focused person it is hard to tell what the MVC example in that link you provided is doing. The "context" in that sample is an abstraction over the actual context. The `Departments` property may actually call `.ToList()`.. and so that would be fine. Previous experience has taught me never to rely on anything `IQueryable` inside your view.. purely due to the deferred execution nature.. and that, even if the connections are managed by your context.. the context itself may be disposed.

Comment: The context itself won't be disposed unless you call `Dispose()` yourself or arrange for someone else to (such as a dependency injection container). It certainly won't be garbage collected because the object implementing `IQueryable` has a reference to it. But if you do dispose your `DbContext`, your point is well-taken.